# Is it good to have a fixed data stored in JSON instead of SQLite

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

i am new to Android, and currently i am developing my own app (for learning).
question is, is it good to store fixed data in form of JSON instead of SQLite (i won't update data at all), i have tried store it in HashMap which is not so good i think.

current code in HashMap is

```
HashMap<Integer, String[]> data = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
data.put(1, new String[]{"asd", "cax", "etc", "etc"});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data looks like an array of strings, one idea is to use Android's built-in resource system.

You can store your data in an XML file called `res/values/arrays.xml`, for example as follows:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

In your code, you can access to the array as follows:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

You can find more information from the links below.

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Comment: yes this is much better, sorry I didn't realize you were talking about fixed data (though it's in the title) :P

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using Sqlite as much as possible as it is slow and takes up a lot of memory. But you say that you won't update the data... so what's the point of storing it? I'm just going to assume you misspoke, in which case a hashmap will work fine as long as you serialize it. On the other hand, it may be easier to convert it to Json as it will allow you to use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

For pre-defined data that won't change, something like that seems OK as long as the data is fairly simple. In the example you gave, though, you could just use a string array instead of a HashMap:

```
String[] data = new String[] {"asd", "cax", "etc", "etc"};
```

For a larger set of pre-defined data, another option would be to use a string array resource.  This also has the advantage of being able to provide different resources for localization of your strings, etc.  More info here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

For more complex data (such as some binary data and not just simple strings) you might want to use raw resources (access through Resources.openRawResource()) or assets (accessed through AssetManager): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: it will have about 50 or more data in that HashMap, and i use key of Integer because i will choose one data with random integer, that's why i use K,V.